# Ошибка в коде C++ Builder

Tags: c++builder, windows, c++

Проблема в коде. Нажимаю на кнопку и дебагер выдает ошибки. Очень прошу помочь. Дело в том, что я ищу в файле текст, который введен в Едите и если такой есть, то начинаю искать текст с Едит2 в том же файле.

```
AsiString x, y;
// ...

void __fastcall TForm3::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    FILE *FP;
    FP = fopen("FP", "rt");
    while(!feof(FP))
    {
        fscanf(FP,"%s",&x);
        if (x==Edit1->Text) while(!feof(FP))
        {
            fscanf(FP,"%s",&y);
            if (y==Edit2->Text) Form5->Show();
        }    
    }
    fclose(FP);
}
```

Comment: а что такое AsiString?о_0

Comment: ну да, не понятно...

Comment: @чипик, AnsiString - один из типов строк, в котором могут содержатся все ascii-символы (больше, чем в обычной string)

Comment: @Crasher, "AsiString" написано же)))

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно поняла: если найдено первое слово, то только тогда ищем второе? 
С большими текстами работать не будет, вы можете переделать, и разбирая файл построчно сразу искать во while.

```
AnsiString x,y,z;
char s[200];
FILE *fp;
if((fp=fopen("мой файл.txt", "r")) == NULL)   //если не найден
    ShowMessage("файл не найден.");
else
{
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        fgets(s,256,fp);    //считали в массив построчно
        z=z+s;              
    }
    x=Edit1->Text;
    if(z.Pos(x))       // поиск
    {
        ShowMessage("Первое слово найдено");
        y=Edit2->Text;
        if(z.Pos(y))
            ShowMessage("Второе слово найдено");
        else
            ShowMessage("Второе слово не найдено");
    }
    else
       ShowMessage("Ничего не найдено");
}
fclose(fp); //закрыли
```